# Get main category upon subcategory by array values php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to categorize by Category and Subcategory. I have selected the Subcategory ID from a user table. I'm getting this:

```
Sports Cricket
Sports Basketball
Sports Volley Ball
News Political
News Business
News Entertainment
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
Sports 
    Cricket
    Basketball
    Volley Ball
News 
    Political
    Business
    Entertainment
```

Here is my code:

```
<?      
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"select * from user where UserId ='3' and Status='act'"));
$show_str = $row["SubcatId"];

$fas = mysqli_query($con, "select * from subcategory where Status='act' ORDER BY catId Asc");
while($ad = mysqli_fetch_array($fas)){
    $SubCategory = $ad["SubCategory"]; //Sub Category Name
    $SubCatId = $ad["SubCatId"]; //Sub Category Id
    $catId = $ad["catId"]; //Category Id
    $array = explode(",", $show_str);
    foreach($array as $item){
        if($item == $SubCatId){
            $fac = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "select distinct Category from category where catId='$catId'"));
            echo $Category = $fac["Category"];
?>
<?=$SubCategory;?>              
<br>
<?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: $show_str is already array then why you are explode again

Comment: also what is inside $row["Interests"] .subcategory id's or category id's

Comment: Its subcategory Id's Like  8,1,2,11,4,6,23,24,21 By using this I need to get category and subcategory Name

Comment: first find distinct category id from subcategory using wherein condition .then foreach distinct cat id echo category name and find subcategory in subcategory table using two conditions where in ('interests') and where cat_id=$cat_id echo all subcategory.hope this will help you

Comment: What's the point of the first query